# Calculate line integral

Tags: integration

For $f(x,y) = 2x + y + 10$, calculate the line integral

$$
\int_{L}{f(x,y)dL}
$$

where $L$ is the straight line between $(1,4)$ and $(5,1)$ in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!, What have you tried?

Comment: I tried calculating the double integral for f(x,y)dxdy from 5 to 1 and 1 to 4 but get the answer 222 which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double integral makes no sense here, as you are looking for a line integral, not area integral. Simply parameterize your line, in this case, $x$ is a good enough parameter anyway:
$$\frac{y-4}{x-1}=\frac{1-4}{5-1}$$
or rather
$$y=4-\frac{3}{4}(x-1)$$
Then integrate over $x$.

Or, of course, as you are integrating a linear function over a linear domain, simply multiply the average of the function in the endpoints with the line length. No integration required, just common sense.

$$\frac{1}{2}(f(1,4)+f(5,1))\sqrt{(5-1)^2+(1-4)^2}=\frac{185}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's *line* integral, not double integral. Parameterize $L$, for example $\langle x,y\rangle =t\langle 1,4\rangle+(1-t)\langle 5,1\rangle$, and write the integral in terms of $t$.